# How do I programmatically empty a cart?

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to empty the cart before a product in the code. I tried

`$this->cartProvider->emptyCart($cart);`

But this did not work and gave an error. I am doing this in Drupal 8. I am adding products in the controller code.

This is how I am fetching the cart.

```
$destination = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
   $productObj = Product::load($productId);

   $product_variation_id = $productObj->get('variations')
     ->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
   $storeId = $productObj->get('stores')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
   $variationobj = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
     ->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')
     ->load($product_variation_id);
   $store = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
     ->getStorage('commerce_store')
     ->load($storeId);



     $cart = $this->cartProvider->getCart('default', $store);

     $this->cartManager->emptyCart($cart);

   if (!$cart) {
    $cart = $this->cartProvider->createCart('default', $store);

   }

   $line_item_type_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
     ->getStorage('commerce_order_item_type');
// Process to place order programatically.
   $cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');
   $line_item = $cart_manager->addEntity($cart, $variationobj);

    $response = new RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('commerce_cart.page')->toString());
    return $response;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the `commerce_cart.cart_manager` service instead.

So `$this->cartManager->emptyCart($cart);` should do the trick.

**Update:** The reason why you get an error is because you try to call `emptyCart` on `$cart` then it's NULL.

You must wrap the line where you empty the cart in an if statement, like this:

```
if (!empty($cart)) {
  $this->cartManager->emptyCart($cart);
}
```